# printing a picture twice on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, printing, preview, image

I want to enable printing a picture from my web page so that the picture will be previewed and printed twice on the same page i.e. 1 A4 with the image printed 2 or 4 times on the same A4.
Is it possible with the FF and IE browsers interface?
Thanks,

Yuval.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why not?

Better to brush up on print stylesheets in order to hide non-relevant items on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Make a print link below the picture or wherever you like. Make it point to another HTML site on which you have placed the pictures as you like (with CSS or plain HTML).

Finally, use javascript (at page load) on that site with the pictures to open the printing dialog in the browser.

Good luck.